# scanner loop doesn't work for one field of method

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java.util.scanner

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EngineStorage {

    Engine[] engines = new Engine[3];

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void fillArray(Engine[] engines) {
        String name;
        double vol;

        for (int i = 0; i < engines.length; i++) {

            System.out.println("name");
            name = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("volume");
            vol = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

when "i" is 0 it works fine but then loop is avoiding "name" variable when "i" is 1 and 2. The result is:

```
name
e32
volume   
2,5


name
volume
3


name
volume
3


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

`nextDouble()` does not skip to the next line, so the next time `nextLine()` is ran, it will read what is left on that line, which is nothing. You can consume the rest of this line with a blank newline like

```
for (int i = 0; i < engines.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("name");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("volume");
        vol = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.nextLine(); //skip to next line
    }
```

Comment: @Yunnosch my bad, did that text contain worse things?

Comment: @Yunnosch ah thanks for heads up, I'll try to pass posts like that through a translator first

Comment: Great. Have fun. Thanks for your contribution.